# " Swift Core Data" Can I use multiple entities without relationship?

Tags: swift, core-data

I want to use `Core Data` ! I need a two or more entities for storing and retrieving data. But I want use without relationships ! If it's possible. Thanks for your attention...

Comment: do the different entities have anything to do with each other?

Comment: No! They're separated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course, when you want to access a particular entity just do

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity")
```

and "Entity" is a poor name for your entity so name it better

Comment: I hope it works...theres more you need like     let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext                   and then you can also sort stuff using sort descriptor :)